# MsSql Url shortener db clash Atomicity failure

Tags: sql-server, atomic

I have a link shortening service, there a large amount of keys in the database these keys expire after a certain amount of time, and then become available to be reassigned.

I recently started getting a lot of clashes so made some amends to create a lock on the table, unfortunately I just had a clash where two leads were created at the same time (to 1'000th of a second)

Wondered if anyone had any ideas on how I can get around this issue, I can not imagine it will happen for a few more weeks but as the business grows this will exasperate the issue.

The column is not unique as we keep a record of each url created in the system, so the url key is used more than once in the table.

Code is something like as below:

```
BEGIN TRAN GetNextUrlToAssign    
DECLARE @res AS INT

EXEC @res = sp_getapplock                 
                @Resource = 'GetKeyForURL',
                @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                @LockTimeout = 20000, -- time in milliseconds.
                @DbPrincipal = 'public'
IF @res < 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'psp_GetKeyForURL: Unable to acquire Lock', 16, 1 )
    ROLLBACK TRAN GetNextUrlToAssign
    --RETURN -1
END         

SELECT TOP 1 @OldIMID = IMID, @URLKey = URLKey
FROM IM A WITH (INDEX(IX_DateAvailable) )
WHERE DateAvailable < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND DateReallocated IS NULL     

UPDATE IM
SET DateReallocated = GETDATE()
WHERE IMID = @OldIMID


EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'GetKeyForURL';

COMMIT TRAN GetNextUrlToAssign
```

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, not really.

I am thinking now that the url shortener does not work in this instance. I would consider using a hashing algorithm not sure which one but something that you could hash datetime-link to Asui2EK or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a little while, but this issue reared it's ugly head and started to create locks on my database.

After speaking with another developer he told me MsSql should not really be used as a queue. There is specific software for creating queues:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

http://www.iron.io/mq

Not had any experience with them, but from a short read they seem like the technology to use.

However I still needed to fix my issue, of slow queries and locking the database, some queries were building up and the slowest were taking 30 seconds to complete.

My solution was to build a second table, with 1000 rows from my main table, a stored procedure ensures that the table was always fully populated every five minutes.

The clever part comes from using a transaction and the lock hints UPDLOCK and READPAST.

UPDLOCK gives you a lock on the row and READPAST allows the next request to read a following row, as in my example below. You will need to have an index on the columns you are using.

This solution gave me a fairly performant query, I tested around 150 links over three clients in two seconds in development.

```
BEGIN TRAN GetNextUrlToAssign

    SELECT TOP 1 @OldID = q.ID, @URLKey = q.URLKey
    FROM Queue q WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE q.Deleted = 0
        AND q.DateReallocated IS NULL   

    UPDATE Queue 
    SET Deleted = 1 
    WHERE ID = @OldID

COMMIT TRAN GetNextUrlToAssign
```

For further reading try this article:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/